# Adding Functionality to a site

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, google-maps-api-3

my name is Cris.

I am a Graphic Designer who decided to take up on a challenge of learning to code. I watched some online videos, bought some books, and finally created my first responsive website. I used HTML5 and CSS3. I know, very limited. I also know that there's a lot more to learn, and I am excited about it. Now, my question is, I want to build another website, but this time I'd like to add certain functionalities, i.e: login using Facebook, enter information that will display on a map, and use some kind of alert that could reach my facebook friends at once ( same used by third application apps on Facebook ). What kind of language do I have to learn in order to apply these functions to my site? 
I know I could simply pay someone to do it for me, but I would really like to at least try to learn/do it myself. I am not expecting a piece of cake kind of thing... 
Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: PHP or Javascript. JS is a client-only, PHP a server-only language. Both of them are useful and easy to learn.

Comment: there are countless different ways to achieve what you want to do. Look into Ruby on Rails, or NodeJS. The things you want to do will require a backend and it will be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Eduardo Dennis - Thank you very much, I will look into that!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What kind of language do I have to learn in order to apply these
>   functions to my site?

You can use JavaScript for client-side, but for backend, you can use node.js(also JavaScript), Java, PHP, Python, Ruby and so on. Personally I suggest node.js. Your website is not going to complex anyway, so use JavaScript as a programming language for frontend and backend. If you decide to use node.js, search for express for server, grunt(or gulp) for build, mongodb(couchdb or rethinkdb) for database

> i.e: login using Facebook

You need to check out [oAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/). You can also use Google or Linkedin accounts. For login with Facebook, check out [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3)

> enter information that will display on a map

[Check this out](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) -> Google Maps Javascript API v3

Comment: Thank you tons Ademllhan!!! I will check those out!!! This is my first time using StockOverflow. I tried another page but was told to get realistic and simply pay someone to do a proper job... That is why I came here for help and am already overwhelmed for all the helping hand I am encountering here! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to dive into JavaScript and jQuery to make your life easier, a little bit of PHP [(for the login)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0), and [Facebook's API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks). I would first focus authenticating to your site using Facebook's Login API (they log in to your site using their Facebook account). Once that's done, work on adding additional functionality.

Comment: Wow!!! I am really excited! Thank you for helping me out, kneeki!